# I want to send email to user from API response in Django?

Tags: python, django

[data image][1]I want to send email to user after this function calling so in first function i m creating customer on razor pay and after fetching customer id i m passing to other function and on.
so in this function get_virtual_account() i am getting all the response from API provided by razor-pay and i need to send that response to user who created the account so how can i do that i am not able to send this response in email.

```
        def create_razor_customer(data):
            logger.info("Inside create_razor_customer")     
            headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
            data=json.dumps(data)
            response = requests.post(settings.API_RAZORPAY+'/customers', headers=headers, data=data, auth=(settings.API_RAZORPAY_KEY, settings.API_RAZORPAY_SECRET))
            logger.info(json.loads(response.content))
            json_response = response.json()
            customer_id = json_response['id']
            logger.info(customer_id)
            get_razor_customer(customer_id)
            return response

        def get_razor_customer(customer_id):
            logger.info("Inside get_razor_customer")
            headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
            response = requests.get(settings.API_RAZORPAY+'/customers/'+customer_id, headers=headers, auth=(settings.API_RAZORPAY_KEY, settings.API_RAZORPAY_SECRET))
            logger.info(json.loads(response.content))
            create_razor_virtual_account(customer_id)
            return response

        def create_razor_virtual_account(customer_id):
            logger.info("Inside create_razor_virtual_account")
            headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
            data = {"receivers": {"types": ["bank_account"]},"description": "razorpay","customer_id": customer_id,"close_by": 1761615838,"notes": {"reference_key": "reference_value"}}
            data=json.dumps(data)
            response = requests.post(settings.API_RAZORPAY+'/virtual_accounts', headers=headers, data=data, auth=(settings.API_RAZORPAY_KEY, settings.API_RAZORPAY_SECRET))
            json_response = response.json()
            virtual_id = json_response['id']
            logger.info(virtual_id)
            logger.info(json_response)
            return response

        def get_virtual_account(virtual_id):
            logger.info("Inside get_virtual_account")
            logger.info(virtual_id)
            headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
            response = requests.get(settings.API_RAZORPAY+'/virtual_accounts/'+virtual_id,headers=headers, auth=(settings.API_RAZORPAY_KEY, settings.API_RAZORPAY_SECRET))
            json_response = response.json()
            logger.info(json_response)
send_account_details()
            return response

        def send_account_details():
            logger.info('Inside send_account_details')
            send_mail('Account Details', 'Details for Razorpay account', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['abhishek@byond.travel',])
            logger.info("sent")
            return "sent"


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/proIH.png
```

Comment: please refer this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/

Comment: Thanks for help.
But my problem is how to pass this parameter in send_account_details() function as the response is from API that is json this is my main problem.
not able to send data in email although email is going with subject and message line only.

Comment: can you please share function calling sequence and which data you need to pass for send_email function?

Comment: look i have uploaded an image .
this data i m getting now i want this data to pass through send_account_details()
this function.

Comment: i also changed the code in get_virtual_account() i m going to call send_account_details()

Comment: checkout the answer given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your response JSON is
`res_data={"duration":1201,"number":6,"result":"FAILURE","url":"http://localhost:8080/job/git_checkout/6/"}`

Then you need to pass this into send_account_details function.

```
def send_account_details(res_data):
    import json
    logger.info('Inside send_account_details')
    body = "JSON Response is : " + json.dumps(res_data) + "\n\n" +  "Details for Razorpay account"
    send_mail('Account Details', body, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['abhishek@byond.travel',])
    logger.info("sent")
    return "sent"
```

Using `json.dumps(res_data)` you can add your JSON to body of email.